# Подсчет сессий на всем сайте

Tags: php, сессия

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код который подсчитывает сессии на сайте.
В данный момент считает количество открытых сессий на каждой странице.
Как сделать что бы сессии считались на всем сайте а не на каждой странице?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$base = "base_sessions.dat"; //файл, в котором храним идентификаторы и время
$LastTime = time() - 50; //через какое время сессии удаляются (время в секундах)
touch($base);
$file = file($base);
$id = session_id(); //выделяем уникальный идентификатор сессии
if ($id!='') {
  $ResFile = array();
  foreach($file as $line) {
    list($sid, $utime) = explode('|', $line);
    if ($utime > $LastTime) {
      $ResFile[$sid] = trim($sid).'|'.trim($utime).PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
  $ResFile[$id] = trim($id).'|'.time().PHP_EOL;
  file_put_contents($base, $ResFile, LOCK_EX);
  $file=$ResFile;
echo "Сейчас на сайте: ".sizeof($file)." пользователей"; 
?>
```

Comment: $base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."base_sessions.dat";

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо большое. Подскажите, а если в папку нужно поместить этот файл? Сейчас опять же только в той папке в которой есть base_sessions.dat считает сессии.

Comment: поместить код из вопроса на каждой странице

Comment: По хорошему вам бы сделать единую точку на сайт и поместить ваш код в middleware. Тогда не пришлось бы ляпать данный код на каждой странице. Но судя по всему у вас костыльно-велосипедное решение